# Executing custom JavaScript Snippets through Non-Interactive console (geth --exec)

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, javascript, console

I have a JavaScript snippet to get the latest transaction to/from an account. After starting the geth instance, I did this in the interactive JS console:

> jsFunction is a function in filename.js

```
>loadScript("/path/to/file/filename.js")
true
>jsFunction(<parameters>)
<Returns the results as expected>
```

But when I try to do the same using the [Non-interactive](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#non-interactive-use-jsre-script-mode) mode, it fails:

```
$ geth --exec 'loadScript("/path/to/file/filename.js")' attach ipc:/path/to/ipc
true
$ geth --exec 'jsFunction(<parameters>)' attach ipc:/path/to/ipc
ReferenceError: 'jsFunction' is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I ran the same command (geth --exec) with normal web3.js functions like **eth.getTransaction**, **eth.getBlock** and it works fine. I don't understand what's wrong with executing custom scripts. Does geth client support this functionality? Am I missing something?

P.S: I am running a private blockchain but didn't mention *--datadir*, *--networkid*, and *--genesis* etc. in the above commands for readability.

Comment: I think you should do everything in a single line `geth --exec 'loadscript("/path/to/file/filename.js"); jsFunction(<params>); ' attach ipc:/path/to/ipc`

Comment: No it is a typo error. It is LoadScript not loadscript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each geth **exec** start one interpreter. So if you define a function into the first, it is not available on the second... Please merge them into one exec:

To sum up:

```
 geth --exec 'loadScript("/path/to/file/filename.js"); jsFunction(...)' attach
```

This also worked:

```
geth --exec "loadscript(\"/path/to/file/filename.js\");jsFunction(<params>)" attach ipc:/path/to/ipc
```

Comment: I am not trying to execute a contract. My question is specific to custom JS code. The **eth.compile.solidity** is a built-in web3.js function.

Comment: Tried changing ' to " and also tried changing **'loadScript("/path/to/file/filename.js")'** to **"loadScript(\"/path/to/file/filename.js\")"**. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Oops. Please ignore the typo. I executed it correctly with a capital S. Still no luck.

Comment: Warning: if you have two different exec, these are two different context. So it is like playing with two distinct interpreters.