# geth exec interpreter persistence

Tags: go-ethereum, console

Running `geth --exec` starts an interpreter. It allows to run geth console commands.
I want to load a javascript function that runs continuously in background in geth. It basically continuously looks for pending transactions and if found, it mines them else doesn't mine continuously (empty blocks unnecessarily).

Currently, I have to manually mine every time and stop mining.

```
geth --jspath "/root/files/js" --exec 'eth.mining;loadScript("mine_pending_transactions.js");eth.mining;' --datadir=/root/.ethereum/devchain attach
```

However, I don't want to mine this manually. In order to automate this, I want to load the script and mine it, as if it's a something like background command that runs in the geth console interpreter.

but I learnt from this Stack-overflow post - ([Executing custom javascript snippets through non-interactive console](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/executing-custom-javascript-snippets-through-non-interactive-console-geth-exe)) that one needs to access the same interpreter.

Is there a way to do that? Even in case of non-interactive console?
Couldn't find anything on official Ethereum documentation.

Comment: Did you consider to use `geth <all you option> js JS_SCRIPT_FILE`?. In the help message it is reported `js                Execute the specified JavaScript files` . You can write a Javascript file that run continuosly in background. I use a javascript file to create continuosly new transactions every x milliseconds. So you can securely achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: What's `<all you option>` ? I'm sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: In your case you need only `geth js javascript_file` but in general you can also specify some options, such as datadir etc.

Comment: Mine is a private geth version. Probably that's why when i run `geth js mine_pending_transactions.js` as you mentioned, I get an error - `listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use`. Hence I tried to mention the datadir where my existing ethereum is in place `geth --jspath "/root/files/js" --datadir=/root/.ethereum/devchain js mine_pending_transactions.js` . But now it returns `datadir already used by another process`

Comment: This problem is related to the fact that there exist already a geth instance that is using the datadir or the port. You have either to stop the existing instance or to start the instance in another datadir AND with a different port.

Comment: So do you mean I can't add a javascript to run continuously on an existing private ethereum network?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80683/discussion-between-briomkez-and-chaitanya-bapat).